# Rewrite Image URL

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, caching, url-rewriting

I am using a RESTful API provided by monitoring software and it works great to pull resource usage graphs. Unfortunately the entire URL including the private hash key is exposed in the image URL meaning I cannot publicly display the information.

As I would like to avoid caching the images by saving them to disk on the web-server, is there any way that I can mask/rewrite the image URL? Currently I use the following format to pull it and this is what is displayed when you right click -> view image info.

http://domain.net/chart.png?type=graph&graphid=&width=840&height=300&id=9776&username=myuser&passhash=mypasshash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url is on the same server, you can use an internal rewrite. If you go to `http://example.com/mygraph.png` it will be internally rewritten to that filepath and the client will still see `http://example.com/mygraph.png` in their url bar.

```
RewriteRule ^mygraph.png$ /chart.png?type=graph&graphid=&width=840&height=300&id=9776&username=myuser&passhash=mypasshash [L]
```

If the image is on an external domain, you'll have to proxy the request. When `http://example.com/mygraph.png` is requested, your server will redo the request to an external server via an internal proxy. Because of this, the external server will see you as the other end of the line, and your server will pass the response of the external server to the client.

```
RewriteRule ^mygraph.png$ http://externaldomain.com/chart.png?type=graph&graphid=&width=840&height=300&id=9776&username=myuser&passhash=mypasshash [P,L]
```

The documentation of `mod_rewrite` can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). [This documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html) gives more information about proxying.